# Twilio Client 1.4 Javascript SDK audio stream display

Tags: javascript, twilio

Based on the following example, I need some changes in the functions.
https://github.com/twilio/client-js-1.4-examples

Currently, it looks like it shows only one stream in the waveform visualization. Is it possible to show the waveform in both ways?

Can we show the stream visualization like the volume indicator?

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The [waveform visualisation](https://github.com/twilio/client-js-1.4-examples#2-waveform-visualization) in that project has an explanatory paragraph that says:

> This example illustrates how the MediaStream returned by Connection.getLocalStream() or Connection.getRemoteStream() can be used to create a visualization of the audio track.

This implies that the visualisation can be generated from any `MediaStream` object you have access to. As the documentation says, this includes the local `MediaStream` returned by `Connection.getLocalStream()` or the remote `MediaStream` returned by `Connection.getRemoteStream()`.

So, yes, you can show more than one waveform visualisation, you just need to do the work to get the `MediaStream` objects from both sides of the call.

Let me know if that helps.